# Problem in parsing JSON data in angular 7

Tags: angular

I am having problem in parsing JSON data in Angular 7. I am sending json data from PHP. But there is some problem in parsing. Probably I am not using the right syntax. I am trying to fetch the value of status. **The error is: Argument of type 'Object' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'.** Please help.

My code is:

PHP:

```php
$users = array('status'=>1);
print json_encode($users);
```

Typescript:

```js
const jsonObj = JSON.parse(data);
console.log("Successful ", jsonObj.status);
```

Comment: Are you getting an error? If so what is it? If not how is the behavior different from what you'd expect?

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: and you think we can understand whats the error?
post ur component and the error.

Comment: The error is: Argument of type 'Object' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'.

Comment: Assuming you are getting the response from PHP server, and you are using `HttpClient` on your Angular 7 application, then you don't need to `JSON.parse(data)` the response. `HttpClient` unlike `Http` returns the JSON object of the response body by default.

Comment: Ok..then how to send from PHP and parse in typescript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all change your PHP code to the following:

```
$users = array('status'=>1);
echo json_encode($users); // echo instead of print
```

Then in js, no need to `JSON.parse` :

```
console.log( data.status );
```

Comment: Thanks almost worked. But had to use data['status'], not data.status.

Comment: This status is the one you have in response object (status, data etc) not the one you return from backend. See your console in chrome to more clarification.

Comment: But when I used data.status, nothing was printed in the console.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use

```
const jsonObj = eval(data);
```

If you have a problem, need to transpile your code which is following.

```
import * as ts from "typescript";

let code: string = `({
    Run: (data: string): string => {
        console.log(data); return Promise.resolve("SUCCESS"); }
    })`;

let result = ts.transpile(code);
let runnalbe :any = eval(result);
runnalbe.Run("RUN!").then((result:string)=>{console.log(result);});
```